# How can we make Google show results from our site with a table (see image inside)?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search-results, structured-data

This is one of the results when you search "Apple company" in Google.

https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/AAPL:US

In the search results, it appears like this:

[image: Apple bloomberg search result]

As you see, Google takes the table (showing Apple industry/sector info) displayed on the page and shows it in the results.

We want to show a similar table on our website - how can we instruct Google to show it in the results like this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe this may be a manual custom integration from Google's side. I'm not sure if there's structured data you can use to get this.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister You mean that this is actually something Bloomberg agreed directly with Google?

Comment: By that I mean it may be something that Google manually configured googlebot to extract from Bloomberg pages.

Comment: Bloomberg does have JSON-LD for the Organization schema which is where Google appears to be getting the data for this display.  However, the resulting rich snippet isn't listed in the [Google search gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't depend on structured data. Google automatically defines important content and shows this in snippets. You can influence this, but no warranty, that your content will be shown like this. I know two popular ways to increase chances put main content into extended snippets:

1. Use tables with `<table>` tag
2. Use lists with `<ul>` tag

These are not the only options available, but they are the most popular. Search for more examples and try to make the same things.

About your example: i see, that they had good work with semantic html5 tags. Them using semantic tags non-typical. Google understood the content of page and used it in SERP.